# Is there an example where the Java code repeatedly executes its own code?

Tags: java, system.out

Example:

```
int a = 10; 
System.out.println(a);
```

How can the value of the variable **`a`** be printed again after a restart of the application?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? `System.out.println(a)` prints the value of a. But you already know that.

Comment: How can the value of the variable a be printed again after a restart of the application?

Comment: Can't you print it the same way as before the restart? What does restarting an application have to do with printing the value of a variable?

Comment: I just want to test it. Could you send me a example?

Comment: Type `public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = 10;
  System.out.println(a);
 }
}` in. your IDE and run it whenever you wish to do so,

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Could you please reverse the vote if you were? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you restart the application the variable a is printed out. You restart it 5 times, a will be printed out 5 times + the original first.

Answer (score -1):

variable (a) will always be printed every time you restart the application or IDE, because every time your restart IDE it will be initialized, you can also comment it out if you don't want it to be printed or read by IDE, by adding (2 forward slash) at the beginning of your code, something like this

```
int a = 10; 
// System.out.println(a);
```